# Auslander-Reiten theory

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose that every submodule of a projective $A-$module $M$ is a projective module.

I want to prove that the functor $DTr$ is isomorphic to the functor $DExt^{1}$$_{A}(-,A)$.

My solution(not complete).

Using The auslander-Reiten formula, we have $Ext^{1}$$_{A}(N,A)$ isomorphic
to $DHom(A,DTrN)$ for some module $N$. Let $M$ be an $A-module$, $Ext^{1}$$_{A}(M,A)$ is isomorphic to $DHom(A,DTrM)$, so $DExt^{1}$$_{A}(M,A)$ is isomorphic to $Hom(A,DTrM)/I(A,DTrM)$.

We must have that $I(A,DTrM) = 0$, but i don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Can anyone suggest some things

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to proof the fact that $I(A, DTrM)=0$ without using too much of the representation theory of hereditary algebras. It is true since for hereditary algebras there are in fact no maps from an injective module to a non-injective, but to prove that, I think you need more theory.

Let me instead give the following hint. I hope it helps. Take a projective resolution of $M$. Since $A$ is hereditary, this is in fact a short exact sequence. Now apply $\operatorname{Hom}(-,A)$ to that to get a long exact sequence. Notice that many terms in fact vanish. Now compare this to the definition of $TrM$.

Comment: Hi Julian, thank you very much. I think I've found the key: $Hom(DA,DTrM) = 0$.

Comment: but I want to ask you for help?

Comment: Can you explain to me how one finds the Auslander-Reiten quiver, i am weak in the calculations.

Comment: @DiegoHavez I can, but the comments to this question is not the right place to ask. May I suggest you ask a different question. But how to compute Auslander-Reiten quivers depends very much on the situation you are in, so it would be helpful to ask about a specific example or class of examples.